# Unable to Upload a file to server: File not found exception in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

How are you all?
 When I am trying to upload a file to server using javascript in cordova, I am getting a "*file not found*" error always.The javascript code is as follows:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var fileURL = "///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myFile.txt"
  var uri = encodeURI("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey = "file";
  options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType = "text/plain";

  var headers = {'headerParam':'headerValue'};
  options.headers = headers;
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(fileURL, uri, onSuccess, onError, options);

  function onSuccess(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
  }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you tried with `var fileURL = "file://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myFile.txt"`?

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting the same error.Please help me.